# Comparing a list with a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of tuples, e.g.

```
journeylist = [("uk_Frank_3734823","342-2432-242-2342",2,3434-3434),("uk_joe_3734823","342-2432-242-2342",2,3434-3434)]
```

and a list, e.g.

```
exclusion = ["joe","jack","alice"]
```

I would like to compare the exclusion list with the 0 index of each tuple. the value can be in any case, e.g. `73473_Jack_uk` and the list has `jack`. They should match. If there is a match the whole tuple must be removed or non matches added to another list.

Comment: `[i for i in journeylist if not any([x.lower() in i[0].lower() for x in exclusion])]`

Comment: What is your question about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this by lower casing the first value and checking the `exclusion` list against it:

```py
lowered_exclusion = [excl.lower() for excl in exclusion]
filtered_journeylist = []
for journey in journeylist:
    first = journey[0].lower()
    if not any(excl in first for excl in lowered_exclusion):
        filtered_journeylist.append(journey)
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to make a minor change: if not any(excl.lower() in first for excl in exclusion): but you saved me a lot of time. and i learnt a new function: any() so thanks again.

Comment: @neo2049 depending on how this is being called, it would probably make sense to lower-case the `exclusion` list outside of the inner loop. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had wrote the code with explanation to make things clearer. :)

```
journeylist = [("uk_Frank_3734823","342-2432-242-2342",2,3434-3434),("uk_joe_3734823","342-2432-242-2342",2,3434-3434)] # Your provided journey list;

exclusion = ["joe","jack","alice"] # Your provided exclusion list;

JourneyList_lowercase = [i[0].lower() for i in journeylist] # Dublicate journey list array in lowercase;

ExclusionList_lowercase = [i.lower() for i in exclusion] # Dublicate exclusion list in lowercase;

Filtered_List = [] # Prepare new list;

for JL in JourneyList_lowercase: # Go trough journey list in lowercase array;
    if not any(EXC in JL for EXC in ExclusionList_lowercase): # Check if we have not any exclusion in our journey list;
        Filtered_List.append(JL) # If we have not any exclusion in our journey list -> add value to our new prepared list;
    
print(Filtered_List)
```